# How to make Flask serve the right content types for static files on Alpine?

Tags: docker, flask, alpine-linux

I am running a Flask webapp in a Docker container based on the `python:2.7-alpine` base image, switching from a Debian base image.

All images served by Flask from the `/static` directory are served with a generic content type `application/octet-stream` instead of the expected specific content types, so that browsers don't display the images correctly.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 7):

The reason is that the Alpine base image does not come with any mime type information. Look at the `apk add` command in the example Dockerfile below. It installs the `mailcap` package, which puts only 68 KB extra and contains a `/etc/mime.types` file.

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine

# install /etc/mime.types
RUN apk update && \
    apk add mailcap && \
    rm /var/cache/apk/*
...
```

Now served PNGs, JPEGs etc. should have the expected Content-type headers.

Answer (score 0):

`apk add --update shared-mime-info`

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=v3.7&name=shared-mime-info&arch=x86_64&repo=main

Comment: This package doesn't add `/etc/mime.types` file.